# How to override onclick event of HTML select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have overriden the click event on my select tag.  When I click on my select tag as default the option list is showing.  But I have to customize that listing and do some other work when I click on select tag.

How can I achieve this?

please see below code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <select id="selectId">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("selectId").onclick = function () {
                alert("second event");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here both event get fired, but I want only the second event.

Comment: You cannot prevent the option list showing when a `select` is clicked. This is controlled by the browser chrome and is beyond the control of javascript. If you want to amend the UI of a select, you need to either use a plugin, or create your own using `div` and `li` elements to mimic the behaviour of a standard `select.

Comment: I think you want to change rendering logic of select tag?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  actually I want multiple option in my select tag.but when I use select tag in window 8 application multiple tag option is not working.so I have to load a custom template when I click on select tag and there I have to show the values of option with check box,there I can select multiple options

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery events for closing and opening select drop down , and not on change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321553/jquery-events-for-closing-and-opening-select-drop-down-and-not-on-change)

Comment: @Xav, if you want multiple selection then you can simply use: <select id="selectId" multiple>

Comment: @Arvind:aravind <select id="selectId" multiple> option does not work in windows phone 8 app.

Comment: @Xav, try using <select id="selectId" `multiple="multiple" size="3"`>

Comment: @Arvind no..it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't override the `select` element `onClick` because it doesn't have one. When you click on a `select` the browser handles it with magic that you can't temper with. You can't simulate a click on it either.

The only things you can do to a select are:

- change its `size` property. You can change it to `1` to force it to close, but you will see an ugly flicker.
- set `hidden` property on all child `option` elements to `true`

You can fake it, something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/BupuU/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <select id="selectId" size="2" multiple="true">
      <option value="volvo" hidden="true">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab"  hidden="true">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel"  hidden="true">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi"  hidden="true">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <div class="mask">Volvo</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.wrapper').click( function(event){
    console.log("sdsd");
    if(true){
       $('#selectId').show();
        $(".mask").hide();
    }
    event.stopPropagation();

});

$('body').click(function(){
    $('#selectId').hide();
    $(".mask").show();
});
```

CSS:

```
.mask{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    min-height:23px;
    min-width:62px;
    vertical-align:top; overflow:hidden; border:solid grey 1px;
}

#selectId{
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
    margin:-18px -30px -18px -8px;
}
```

This is only a starting point. You can build from here.