# Intercepting the call to display of dropdown in Webview

Tags: android, webview

While using webview, i can set up a `WebChromeClient`on it and intercept the alerts(and then customize it also) by overriding

```
onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,JsResult result)
```

Is there a way that i can intercept the display of dropdown dialogs( that comes from `<select>` tags of HTML)? Basically i wanted to customize the view of that dialog? I tried overriding a few functions in `WebChromeClient` but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<select>` elements are handled inside the rendering engine, there are no callbacks provided by WebView for customizing them.

The best you can do is to use JavaScript code in the web page you display. See for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23515955/4477684.