# JQuery multiselect checkbox dropdown event handling

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I have the following code for JQuery multi select checkbox dropdown.

I can catch the event when the user selects the checkboxes. But I want the event to be fired when the user selects checkboxes and closes the dropdown ? I don't want to insert the DB for every checkbox selection , rather when the user selects his checkboxes and closes the dropdown ? And also should be able to retrieve the selected values. Thanks

```
<div id="multiCheckbox">
    <select name="busiUnit" id="day" multiple="multiple"
        data-native-menu="false">
        <option>Business Unit</option>
        <option value="1">Finance</option>
        <option value="2">R&D</option>
        <option value="3">Sales</option>
        <option value="4">Inventory</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$("#day").change(function () {
    var str = '',
        busiArray = array();

    $("select#day option:selected").each(function () {
        str = $( this ).text();
        busiArray.push(str);
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery events for closing and opening select drop down , and not on change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321553/jquery-events-for-closing-and-opening-select-drop-down-and-not-on-change)

Comment: You don't listen to change event of any checkboxes in your code. In fact there is no checkboxes in your HTML.

Comment: @Vohuman he wants to run code upon closing popup/selectmenu, so change event isn't needed here :) custom selectmenus are converted into a popup with checkboxes within for multi-select.

Comment: @Omar Yeah, that seems to be true, didn't notice the jquery-mobile tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple-select selectmenu is converted into a popup. That popup receives id of `select` And `-listbox` added to it dynamically.

Attach `popupafterclose` and then run your code.

```
$(document).on("popupafterclose", "#day-listbox", function () {
    /* code */
});
```