# Automatic select in form by JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have trouble to select an option automatically with the following elements.(select an option says, text = 9.5)

@David Thomas's method works:

```
$('#sizeSelect option').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === '9';
}).prop('selected', true);
```

However, it didn't appear as I expected. It didn't appear as if chosen in the form; when I clicked, it actually did.

But didn't look like an ordinary click by mouse:

[image]

The left side 2 chinese charater with (US) is by script...on the right side is by clicking mouse makes it appear (US 9). Centre picture is when i try to click the left picture, it already show me US 9 was selected. but just not shown as the picture on the right

The complete HTML code is below:

```
<div class="ui-buying-flyout ui-box none">
 <span class="headline ui-txt-center width100per block">size and amount </span>
  <div class="ui-table width100per ui-box">
   <ul class="ui-row">
    <li class="ui-cell width50per">
     <div class="ui-select width100per ui-box">
        <p class="arrow-d font12 right"></p>
        <span class="ui-box e-select" id="sizeSpan">Size(US)</span>
        <select class="select width100per ui-box e-option" id="sizeSelect" autocomplete="off">
            <option currUpc="" >Size(US)</option>
            <option currUpc="00883412740890">8</option>
            <option currUpc="00883412740906">8.5</option>
            <option currUpc="00883412740913">9</option>
            <option currUpc="00883412740920">9.5</option>
            <option currUpc="00883412740937">10</option>
            <option currUpc="00883412740951">11</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

reference link: m.nikestore.com.hk/product/315122-111/detail.htm

Comment: Which elements are you trying to select?

Comment: Did you try adding a 'selected' attribute?

Comment: I would like to select an option says, text = 9

Comment: @kkaosninja I would like to select an option says, text = 9

Comment: @meirshapiro tried in jquery, not worked

Comment: Please show us what you've tried with jQuery.

Comment: @meirshapiro
$("select[class='select width100per ui-box e-option']").find("option:eq(3)").attr("selected",true);

Comment: Your jQuery suggests you simply want to pick the fourth `<option>`; this implies that you already know which `<option>` you want (do you discover that from somewhere else in your code), or do you - in reality - have to select the correct `<option>` based on its value or text?

Comment: @DavidThomas I just want to make it works before make it getting complicated, I want to select based on text

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Closing/Opening Events for a Select Option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321553/jquery-events-for-closing-and-opening-select-drop-down-and-not-on-change)

Answer (score 2):

Your original selector:

```
$("select[class='select width100per ui-box e-option']")
```

Will select a `<select>` element with a `class` attribute whose value is *exactly* `"select width100per ui-box e-option"`; not a `<select>` element with all those classes, but only a `<select>` element with those precise classes in that precise order.

That said, I'd suggest changing your selector to a less 'fussy' selector that will select any `<select>` element with those classes (regardless of the order in which they appear in the attribute):

```
$('select.select.width100per.ui-box.e-option')
```

Though this will select *all* `<select>` elements with all of those classes. If that's not what you want, then give that the relevant `<select>` has an `id` assigned to it, I'd suggest instead using the `id` (which must be unique within the document, an `id` ***cannot be used again, or shared with any other elements in the same page***, this cannot be emphasized enough); which will select only the one, specific element with that specific `id` property/attribute:

```
$('#sizeSelect')
```

As your comment implies that you want to select an `<option>` based on its text (`"9"`), I'd suggest:

```
$('#sizeSelect option')
```

to select the `<option>` descendants of the `<select>`, and then filtering that collection, using the `filter()` method:

```
$('#sizeSelect option').filter(function () {
    // $.trim() returns the string it's given, but removes
    // leading and trailing white-space, so $.trim('   9   ')
    // returns '9'

    // $(this) is always the current element we're iterating over,
    // $(this).text() returns the text of the current element:

    // the comparison $.trim($(this).text()) === '9'
    // returns a Boolean, which will be either true or false
    // if it returns true we retain the current element in the collection
    // if it returns false we discard the current element:
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === '9';
})
```

Chaining that with `prop()` to set the `selected` property to `true`:

```
$('#sizeSelect option').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === '9';
}).prop('selected', true);
```

```js
$('#sizeSelect option').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) === '9';
}).prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-select width100per ui-box">
  <p class="arrow-d font12 right"></p>
  <span class="ui-box e-select" id="sizeSpan">Size(US)</span>
  <select class="select width100per ui-box e-option" id="sizeSelect" autocomplete="off">
    <option currUpc="">Size(US)</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740890">8</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740906">8.5</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740913">9</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740920">9.5</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740937">10</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740951">11</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Of course, this is quite possible using 'plain' JavaScript, in modern browsers:

```
// getting a reference to all <option> elements from
// the #sizeSelect element:
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#sizeSelect option');

// using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over each
// of the found <option> elements:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(opt) {
  // opt is the array-element from the (array-like)
  // NodeList over which we're iterating (here the <option>;

  // we're setting the selected property of the element to
  // the Boolean value returned by the assessment;
  // if the trimmed textContent (' 9  ' becomes '9') is
  // equal to '9' then it's set to true, otherwise to false:
  opt.selected = opt.textContent.trim() === '9';
});
```

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#sizeSelect option');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(opt) {
  opt.selected = opt.textContent.trim() === '9';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-select width100per ui-box">
  <p class="arrow-d font12 right"></p>
  <span class="ui-box e-select" id="sizeSpan">Size(US)</span>
  <select class="select width100per ui-box e-option" id="sizeSelect" autocomplete="off">
    <option currUpc="">Size(US)</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740890">8</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740906">8.5</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740913">9</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740920">9.5</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740937">10</option>
    <option currUpc="00883412740951">11</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Selectors Level 3: Attribute-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
  - [Selectors Level 3: id-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: thanks for your detail explanation. I now found that I learnt alot by reading your suggestion. Thanks! you must be a great programmer.

however, it didn't appeared like what i supposed. With the script It looks like didn't get chosen in the form . When I clicked, it actually did. But not appeared like ordinary click by mouse. Are these related to the html below(these are on top of the script I provieded:

<div class="ui-table width100per ui-box">
    <ul class="ui-row">
     <li class="ui-cell width50per">
     <div class="ui-select width100per ui-box">
    <p class="arrow-d font12 right"></p>

Comment: with picture added to make it clear, thanks so much! your help is much appreciated

Comment: So, it's being selected but it doesn't look like a user-select (no blue background/highlighting)?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Closing/Opening Events for a Select Option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321553/jquery-events-for-closing-and-opening-select-drop-down-and-not-on-change)

Comment: @DavidThomas The left side 2 chinese charater with (US) is by script...on the right side is by clicking mouse makes it appear (US 9). Centre picture is when i try to click the left picture, it already show me US 9 was selected. but just not shown as the picture on the right

Comment: @mk117 it seems related. I am too deficit on knowleges..how to integrate them

Comment: @DavidThomas reference link: http://m.nikestore.com.hk/product/315122-111/detail.htm

Comment: @Steven Wong: You could either try `change()` or `select()` events for updating the image on the right. Or maybe a Jquery `each()` with `select` selector that has `if($(this).prop('selected', true)) { /*update image on the right*/ }`