# Handle event fired when selected drop down option is selected again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I have a select element like this:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I have written a `onchange` event:

```
$(document).on('change', '[id*=select1]', function () {
            alert('in change select1');
});
```

Now suppose I have option 1 selected and I again go and select the same option (option1), then the change event is not fired.

I want to handle the event which will be fired in this case. Can anyone tell me which even will be fired when I try to select the option which is already selected?

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742739/run-change-event-for-select-even-when-same-option-is-reselected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '[id*=select1]', function () {
    alert('in change select1');
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kzou0a7p/)