# Trigger change event if I click on already selected option

Tags: jquery, select, html-select, onchange

How can I trigger change event if I click on already selected option.
For example I have following options in dropdown

- Red
- Blue
- Green

and Blue option is selected. Now I want that if I click again on blue item then the change event should fire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run change event for select even when same option is reselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742739/run-change-event-for-select-even-when-same-option-is-reselected)

Answer (score 1):

Running the `change` even when the user selects the selected option is a known problem - you can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742739/run-change-event-for-select-even-when-same-option-is-reselected) about it.

Now, when you know how to trigger an event whenever a user selects any option, you can simply store the last used value and check if the same item is selected.

```js
var previousValue;
$("select")
    .mouseup(function() {
        var open = $(this).data("isopen");

        if (open) {
            if (this.value === previousValue)
            {
                alert("The same select has been clicked");
            }
        }

        previousValue = this.value;
    
        $(this).data("isopen", !open);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Red</option>
  <option selected>Green</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this with the `click` event, not the `change` event.

If you select the same option, the `change` event doesn't fire because you selection didn't change.

Comment: Click event on select option does not work in chrome.