# Detect when <select>'s menu closed even if value unchanged

Tags: jquery, html, focus

I'm building an application that uses a barcode reader for input. The application uses a `<select>` element for changing between scan modes.

If a user opens the mode selection menu, but then chooses the same mode they are in presently, then I cannot blur the `<select>` using the following:

```
$("#mode-select").change(function() {
  //switch the mode
  //...
  $(this).blur();
});
```

This becomes problematic due to the scanner input. The scanner acts as a keyboard, and ends a successful scan by submitting a return character. If the `<select>` has focus this opens the mode selection menu unexpectedly, causing people to call my office.

[Illustration here](https://jsfiddle.net/wfb5q1hf/): select any new value and the `<select>` loses focus. Select the same value and it does not. I would like it to lose focus regardless.

How can I blur the `<select>` in this instance, or otherwise implement similar behavior?

Comment: existing html ?

Comment: @NalinAggarwal plain old <select> containing a handful of <option>s - not sure why that would be relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742739/run-change-event-for-select-even-when-same-option-is-reselected?

Comment: The change event should get invoked, even if the same value is chosen?

Comment: @Pineda frankly I don't care if the rest of it is invoked - I just need to ensure that the <select> loses focus afterwards in either case