# Fire change() event even when selection hasn't changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to override the general behavior of an HTML `select` element by making it fire the change event even when the selected option hasn't changed.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: i want the change event handler below to be fired even when the same option is selected

Comment: store the value on the first selection, compare the old value with the new value in new selection

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee to store or do something the event handler should fire to start with when the same option is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:-

HTML :

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JS :

```
$("select").mouseup(function() {
    var flag = $(this).data("flag");
        var cur_val = $(this).val();
    if(flag) {
        alert(cur_val);
    }
    $(this).data("flag", !flag);
});
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9h7d793/3/).

Give it a try, this should work.

Comment: duplicate of:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742739/run-change-event-for-select-even-when-same-option-is-reselected

Comment: @rahul_m thanks,that is working

Comment: Your most welcome mate !

Comment: @rahul_m though i'm still looking for a much standard solution

Comment: There is no such event or standard solution you will get as pure jquery event or something