# How can i get dropdown box value on every click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one dropdown box. I want to get that's value on very click on option or onchange. Example: If i select any value continously two times onebyone i am not getting the value fist time only i am getting.

how can i get value on every option click ?

js:

```
$("#ddrp1").on("change", function() {
 alert(this.value); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="ddrp1">
<option value="">Select an option</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
<option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
<option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

JSfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/LwwFL/309/

Comment: What's wrong with your code? As I see into your fiddle, you get the value of option when it's changed.

Comment: `If i select any value continously two times onebyone i am not getting the value fist time only i am getting`, thats because when you select same option for second time, the `change` event wont be triggered because the option didnt change

Comment: Only one time changed..pls click again the same value..u will not get. check it

Comment: Sudhir Bastakoti:- u understood correctly. But i need the value second time also..how do it?  bcoz every time i want to call  some other event

Comment: Possible duplicate [Run change event for select even when same option is reselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742739/run-change-event-for-select-even-when-same-option-is-reselected)

Comment: Typically, what you need is the `$("#ddrp1 option").on("click", function() { });` handler. Yet, not all browsers fully support it, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749597/jquery-select-option-click-handler

Comment: Thanks guys..I got idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution working also when select value is not changed (same option clicked):

```
$("#ddrp1").mouseup(function() {
    var isOpen = $(this).data("isopen");

    // only when mouseup event is called and select is still open
    if (isOpen) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }

    $(this).data("isopen", !isOpen);
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/benjib/q42tj0bw/

Answer (score 0):

try this,Its working for me

html:-

```
 <select id="ddrp1" class="form-control" onchange="DemoEvent(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
```

javascript:-

```
 var array = [];
    function DemoEvent(val) {
        array.push(val);
        for (i = 0; array.length > i;i++){
            if (array[i] != val) {
                alert();
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just change onchange to on click [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaymakwana365/98qpktkk/)

```
<select id="ddrp1">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
</select>

$("#ddrp1").click( function() {
   alert(this.value); 
});
```