# select onchange same value

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, onblur

Is there a way to trigger an event if I open a dropdown select, and select the same value **WITHOUT** clicking away to switch focus?

I tried

1. `onblur`, but it only works if I make an extra click outside the select.
2. `onchange`, but it only works if I select a different value.

I need to trigger an event simply if I open the dropdown and select anything, regardless of whether it is the same or different.

```
<select name='show1' id='show1' onblur='dosomething(this);'>
<option value='1'>One</option>
<option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it will be better, if you will show us, what you have tried till now.

Comment: as i said, i tried onchange and i tried onblur, and none of that works as intended

Comment: I know, so show us your coding and problem. That will help to know your exact problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647282/is-there-an-onselect-event-or-equivalent-for-html-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what library or framework you use, but this is quite simple. You are essentially looking for two things to be true:

1. Test that the control was clicked.
2. Test that a value (any value) has been selected, --or-- is still selected.

Number 2 can be achieved with something like...

```
var elem = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var value = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
```

It's then a simple matter to test that it is non-empty.

Comment: i understand that i can do #1 with onclick. How do I get to #2?

Comment: correct me if I got you correctly. I do an onclick and then inside the function i test if there is anything selected. and if yes - i run the actual function?

Comment: Yes. That should give you what you need.

Comment: In addition to testing for ´click´ you should also check for keyboard events (a user might use the keyboard to change selection). In that case you should probably listen to ´keyup´ and when the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd have to use the onClick-event and store the previously selected item in a variable.

Here's a quick example which I think could use some refactoring :-)

```
    var dropboxOpen = false,
        oldItem     = null;
    function onClick(e) {
        if (dropboxOpen) {
            if (oldItem && oldItem === e.target.value) {
                console.log('same selected');
            }
            oldItem = e.target.value;   
        }        
        dropboxOpen = !dropboxOpen;
     }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtHPV/

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work reliably if using the keyboard for navigation. The firing of the "onclick" event seems erratic and doesn't always change in the ways I would expect, at least in my tests in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery

You can try **[focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)** event.