# Get input data without refreshing page

Tags: php, javascript

I want to store input data from a select without refreshing page. I have this code:

```
<p class="inf" >   
    Select:
    <select id="chose" >
        <option value="0">choose citty</option>
        <option value="cluj">Cluj</option>
        <option value="bucuresti">Bucuresti</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

I want, if it's possible to use javascript. Thank you.

Comment: It's possible; it's called AJAX.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647282/is-there-an-onselect-event-or-equivalent-for-html-select


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647282/is-there-an-onselect-event-or-equivalent-for-html-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you want a technology called AJAX. It allows for sending data back to the server without refreshing the page. The easiest implementation of this is [jQuery's Ajax Method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)