# submit a html form by choosing the already selected option of a select element

Tags: html, forms, select, submit

I have small html calculator, where you can enter two numbers, with two separate buttons to either add or subtract them, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<%= actionURL %>" >
    <input type="text" name="x" value="${x}"/>
    <input type="text" name="y" value="${y}"/>
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="add"/>
    <input type="submit" name="subtract" value="subtract"/>
</form>
```

I would like to replace the two buttons with a `select` element, that would submit the form when the user chooses one of the options. So far I have the following:

```
<form method="post" action="<%= actionURL %>" >
    <input type="text" name="x" value="${x}"/>
    <input type="text" name="y" value="${y}"/>
    <select name=operation onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="add">Add</option>
        <option value="subtract">Subtract</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Now I get a dropdown box with the options "Add" and "Subtract". Whenever I choose "Subtract", the form gets submitted, and I can check the `operation` parameter of the request back on the server. But clicking on the dropdown box and then on "Add" doesn't fire the `onChange` event, since "Add" is already selected, and so the form is not submitted. Is there any way I can submit the form, when the user chooses the already selected option?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647282/is-there-an-onselect-event-or-equivalent-for-html-select. (Essentially you're looking for a way to fire an event on selection, not change.)

Comment: Please consider selecting an answer or add more specific information if none of the answers satisfy your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because "Add" is already selected and no change happens. You should add another element to the select:

```
<form method="post" action="<%= actionURL %>" >
    <input type="text" name="x" value="${x}"/>
    <input type="text" name="y" value="${y}"/>
    <select name=operation onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select operation</option>
        <option value="add">Add</option>
        <option value="subtract">Subtract</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a submit button to submit the form where you can set operation parameter depeding upon what value is selected in dropdown and can perform operation..