# Javascript string is not an function

Tags: javascript, select, undefined, onchange

I'm trying to add an `onChange` event on an `select` element. The html looks like this:

```
<select name="to" onChange="if(type(this.selectedIndex) != undefined){ alert('hello'); }">
    <option value="newsletter">Alle nieuwsbrief-abonnees</option>
    <option value="customer_all">Alle klanten</option>
    <option value="customer_group">Klantengroep</option>
    <option value="customer">Klanten</option>
    <option value="affiliate_all">Alle affiliates</option>
    <option value="affiliate">Affiliates</option>
    <option value="product">Producten</option>
    <option value="marketing">Alle Marketing Abbonnees</option>
    <option value="marketing_all">Alle Marketing</option>
    <option value="subscriber">Alle Nieuwsbrief Abbonnees &amp; Marketing Abbonnees</option>
    <option value="all">Alle Klanten &amp; Marketing</option>
    <option value="old_brian">Oude lijst Brian</option>
    <option value="old_dunamis">Oude lijst Dunamis</option>
    <option value="old_frohlich">Oude lijst Frohlich</option>
    <option value="old_gaithers">Oude lijst Gaithers</option>
    <option value="old_gospel7">Oude lijst Gospel7</option>
    <option value="old_lifeshop">Oude lijst Lifeshop</option>
    <option value="old_meyer">Oude lijst Meyer</option>
    <option value="old_opwekking">Oude lijst Opwekking</option>
    <option value="old_pelgrim_kerken">Oude lijst Perlgim Kerken</option>
    <option value="old_pelgrim_klanten">Oude lijst Pelgrim Klanten</option>
    <option value="old_pelgrim_pers">Oude lijst Pelgrim Pers</option>
    <option value="old_pelgrim_scholen">Oude lijst Pelgrim Scholen</option>
    <option value="old_test">Oude lijsten test</option>
</select>
```

[Here's an JSFIDDLE of it](http://jsfiddle.net/hN9UF/)

The onchange script came from an answer on stackoverflow: [Is there an onSelect event or equivalent for HTML ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647282/is-there-an-onselect-event-or-equivalent-for-html-select)

But i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function
```

I'm clueless, what's the problem? Can't you do an if statement in an onChange event? Or is it something else?

Comment: The comment on that answer is wrong about how to check the "selectedIndex" property.

Comment: I thought that already, but i'm not that good at js so i couldn't grasp the right way to do it :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`type` is not a built-in function. `typeof` is an operator, though, that may be what you wanted; it returns a string:

```
if (typeof this.selectedIndex !== "undefined") // But see below
```

But note that `selectedIndex` is never `undefined` on `select` elements. It may be -1, to indicate no selection, but not `undefined`. So:

```
if (this.selectedIndex !== -1)
```

---

Regarding the error: My guess is that you have a global variable called `type`, and that it contains a string. That would give you the error `TypeError: string is not a function`.

Comment: Thank you sir, that did it. the typeof was indeed the fix. Now using the second recomendation. Will accept when the time has come. Thanks again :D

Comment: @Mathlight Sorry for the confusion I've caused, and thanks for T.J Crowder for the correction!