# Google Charts - Category Filter Callback?

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to call a function whenever an option in a category filter is selected?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647282/is-there-an-onselect-event-or-equivalent-for-html-select) is what I'm looking for, but since I'm using Google's API I'd assume I can't access the element's HTML and attach an onChange() event. The only callback Google docs mention is setOnLoadCallback(), but it's only for the entire dashboard.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be possible with a statechange listener:

```
function stateChangeHandler() {
    console.log("hello");
};

google.visualization.events.addListener(**name-of-your-filter**, 'statechange', stateChangeHandler);
```